# SwiftUI - How to display paged tabs (via tabview) within a single view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabs

I'm trying to create a way of navigation via tabs that looks something like this: [image]

where there are multiple tabs, and you can swipe to get to the one on the left, or tap it to achieve the same behavior. I thought maybe using TabView with `.tabViewStyle(.page)` could potentially lead me to this type of navigation:

```
@State var tabs: [String] = []
...
    TabView {
            ForEach(0 ..< days.count, id: \.self) { i in
                ZStack {
                    Button(days[i]) {}
                }
                .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            }
            ZStack {
                Button("Add") {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        days.append("tab")
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
```

which gave me something like this:
[image]

Here, I have one tab that has a button "add" that adds other tabs "tab". But as you can see, you can only see one tab in the view at a time. I really like the "swiping" behavior of tabs, so I'm wondering **is there a way to implement paged tab views such that multiple tabs can be seen at the same time**, like in the picture above?

Comment: Have you tried horozontal scroll view with an hstack?

Comment: @cora yes, however I'm not sure how to emulate the swiping motion of a tab view, i.e if im on one tab and swipe to the left, it should transition to that tab. any ideas?

Comment: There are solutions how to achieve paging in a scroll view.

Comment: @cora could you please provide a link?